# rounding to nearest percentage

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a formula such as

```
count(s.listing_id) / count(a.listing_id) * 100
```

and I want to round to the nearest whole percentage,

`would ROUND(count(s.listing_id) / count(a.listing_id) * 100),1) work?`

as in if the value is .03881 should be 39?

Comment: Is your formula correct? Did you want to perform multiplication first and then do the division?

Comment: also [seems to be 3.9](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02305a565c3a70e234c021c5c75995d7) rather than 39. Using SQL too since I'm rusty on my 100 times table :-).

Answer (score 0):

`ROUND( count(s.listing_id) / count(a.listing_id) * 100 )` rounds to a whole number.

ref: [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding more brackets. Your formula still technically works in the way of PEDMAS, but this will future proof it.

```
ROUND(((count(s.listing_id) / count(a.listing_id)) * 100)),0)
```

Comment: You should change the  1 to a zero, because user wants no digits

Comment: I suspect SQL standard, or at least the existing implementation, defines the order of maths operations and that isn't going to change.